# Creating public key hash

Tags: address, key, python, hash

Could somebody please point me to a piece of working Python 3.7 code that generates a Tezos public key hash out of seed, password and e-mail address?

Everything I could find so far is always a mix of python 2 and 3 code which produces errors due to change in data types or acceptance of magicbyte size. I am not a programmer. I’m just trying to create some code that helps me finding my lost password. (Yes I know tools like JtR, crunch and some more others, they are nice but don’t satisfy my requirement’s in full so I started to try out creating something on my own). I know the python code on the fundraiser page of github which creates the mentioned error.

Answer (score 5):

Try https://github.com/murbard/pytezos/blob/master/pytezos/crypto.py

```
from pytezos.crypto import Key

key = Key(key='mnemonic', passphrase='******', email='foo@bar.com')
key.public_key_hash()
>>> edpk...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. tried it, but I will need to install some other packages for that. Struggling with pkg-config at the moment, which is needed to install secp256k1. Will let you know as soon I have figured it out. As said, I am not a programer…. :-(